# Breakline in math mode - no equation

Tags: math-mode

I've found many questions about math mode and linebreak but each time about many equations. My problem is in a function definition. It's really long and using `\text`. So I have an `overfull \hbox` and want to split the definition in two part.

```
$
foo: bar \rightarrow foofoo = 
\begin{cases} \text{really long text} \\ 
\text{some other text}
\end{cases}
$
```

I want a break line after the `=` to avoid the `\overfull \hbox`

How can I performed this?

Comment: A `cases` environment in line is not among my choices.

Comment: For something so tall, display math would work better.  Have a look at the various amslatex environments like multline, gather, align.  For inline math, you can just break the equation into parts by ending with a $ and starting with a new $.

Comment: @egreg : What would be your choice?

Comment: Either spelling out the definition or using a display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I placed the item in `\displaystyle` math with `\[...\]` rather than inline math with `$...$`.  Then, I just used a left-aligned stack to manually break up the really long text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\#}
\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
\[
foo: bar \rightarrow foofoo = 
\begin{cases} \Longstack[l]{really long text really long text\#
   really long text really long \#
  text really long text really long text really \#
  long text } \\ 
\text{some other text}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your code: `! Undefined control sequence. \@readMANYrows ...ROWcellindex@}{0}\whileboolexpr 
                                                  {test {\nottoggle {@doneRO...`

Comment: @RomainPicot Based on that error message, I am guessing that your `etoolbox` package is out of date.

Comment: @RomainPicot For comparison, my log file reveals: `Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX`

Comment: Yes it's an older version, with an update it's better ty